# Windows Remote Management snap-in

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a windows 7 PC and several Windows 2008 Hyper-v core servers. I want to use remote management snap-ins to manage the hyper-v core server, but found that I couldn't add the firewall snap-in, but I can add "disk management", "event viewer" snap-ins.

In the windows 7 PC, I opened a MMC console, there's a list of available snap-ins.
when I chose "windows firewall with advanced security on local computer" and select from "another computer", then type the hyper-v server name, I got the following error:

> An object(Built-in security principal) with the following name cannot be found. Check the selected object types and locations for accuracy and ensure that you have typed the object name correctly, or remove this object from the selection.

If I add other snap-ins such like "Disk Management", there's no problem. I noticed that the "from this location" is the "windows 7 PC computer name" instead "WORKGROUP when I add the firewall snap-in, but others are "WORKGROUP". Could this be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that can't be remotely managed (or with restrictions): firewall, devices, active-x, component services, auth manager, and the list goes on.

Comment: This guide says I can remote manage the firewall, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/fe80f0aa-0697-4657-a1da-19d36b036698/

Comment: That guide applies to Windows Server 2012 being managed from a Windows 8 client. That is not the software you are using.